# Can I see the full referrer in Google Analytics Real-Time?

Tags: google-analytics

Maybe I am just overlooking it, but I cannot find a way to see the full referrer in Google Analytics Real-Time overview (only the domain). Is this information available somewhere?

Comment: It seems to be possible, but not sure how exactly as I haven't tried it myself: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/diPz2tuGW3w

Comment: @nyuen, that thread seems a bit strange - the Request URI is not the same thing as the referrer, full or otherwise.